# Why WinInet's InternetErrorDlg is not correctly dealing with ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED?

Tags: delphi, wininet

I'm trying to handle the `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` error using the following function:

```
function CallInternetErrorDialog(AInetOpenRequest: HINTERNET; ALastError: DWORD): DWORD;
var
  P: Pointer;
begin
  Result := InternetErrorDlg(GetDesktopWindow()
                            ,AInetOpenRequest
                            ,ALastError
                            ,FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                            ,P);

  // Only to check result (this is not important right now)
  case Result of
    ERROR_SUCCESS: OutputDebugString('ERROR_SUCCESS');
    ERROR_CANCELLED: OutputDebugString('ERROR_CANCELLED');
    ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY: OutputDebugString('ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY');
    ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE: OutputDebugString('ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE');
  end;

  if ALastError = ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED then
    Result := ERROR_INTERNET_FORCE_RETRY;
end;
```

This is merely a helper function built around the InternetErrorDlg function and it's very simple with two parameters. The first one is the Open Request Handle, returned by HttpOpenRequest funcion. The second one is the result of GetLastError function.

On my implementation, when GetLastError returns `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED`, i call that function like this (example):

```
CallInternetErrorDialog(OpenRequestHandle,ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED)
```

The behaviour I expected was the System's Select Certificate default dialog being shown to the user select some certificate:

[image: Select Certificate Dialog]

However, the internal call to InternetErrorDlg only returns zero (ERROR_SUCCESS) imediatelly, without show anything.

For those claiming the full source code here goes the roadmap. I'll not put the entire code because it is very extense. The full unit has more than 800 lines of code:

1. InternetOpenHandle := InternetOpen(...);
2. InternetConnectHandle := InternetConnect(InternetOpenHandle,...);
3. HttpOpenRequestHandle := HttpOpenRequest(InternetConnectHandle,...);
4. HttpSendRequestResult := HttpSendRequest(HttpOpenRequestHandle,...);
5. GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED
6. CallInternetErrorDialog(ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED,HttpOpenRequestHandle);
7. Repeat from step 4;
8. GetLastError = ERROR_INTERNET_SECURITY_CHANNEL_ERROR
9. End

The step 6 call my function that simply call the `InternetErrorDlg`, with the following (already replaced) parameters:

```
InternetErrorDlg(GetDesktopWindow()
                ,HttpOpenRequestHandle
                ,ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED
                ,FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FILTER_FOR_ERRORS or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_CHANGE_OPTIONS or FLAGS_ERROR_UI_FLAGS_GENERATE_DATA
                ,P);
```

With these parameters, the `InternetErrorDlg` function returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` immediatelly, without show anything to the user, so, what kind of tratament was done for the `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` error?

The error at step eight is absolutely natural, because after the server send the `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` it wait that the next attempt (`HttpSendRequest`) already be loaded with a valid certificate. This proofs that the `InternetErrorDlg` function, despite your successful result, is not doing what it should

Please see the CallInternetErrorDialog again for more information.

Comment: Not checking the return value of `InternetErrorDlg` before assuming that it worked and that `ALastError` is valid. You should be checking the API call and comparing the results to the [documented return values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384694(v=vs.85).aspx) in order to see if the function was successful or not before just blindly using the ALastError value.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your comment. Let me explain something. This function is not checking the return value because it is a prototype yet, but only to clarify the things, i've checked the result using a case statement and i've edited the question. Now I know that `InternetErrorDlg` is returning `ERROR_SUCCESS`. ALastError is an input parameter and it is *REALLY* `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED`, so, let me know if I'm wrong: `InternetErrorDlg`called with `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` should not display the Select Certificate dialog?

Comment: @Carlos, did you see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2009/06/23/how-to-call-interneterrordlg-to-deal-with-certificate-issues-on-ssl-connections-c/)?

Comment: @whosrdaddy Yes, i saw it. That article shows soleily how to use the `InternetErrorDlg` to deal with certificate issues, and that I'm already doing. My question here is a little bit different. I want to know why the `InternetErrorDlg` function, when used to deal with the `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED ` error, does not show any windows to user choose some certificate (installed certificate?). The article shows only the "happy path", it does not speak about what's the behaviour of the `InternetErrorDlg` function in every case

Comment: I added this link because it show a **complete** expample how to use InternetErrorDlg (albeit in C), more specifc, the code used **before** calling the dialog seems to be of interest. If you want to receive an answer from someone, you will have to present an MVCE...

Comment: Dear @whosrdaddy, I will not put more code because there are no util code to post. Please understand, I guess the `InternetErrorDlg` function is not doing the right thing. This funcion is used to deal with various WinInet errors and, for me, the correct behaviour of this function on deal with `ERROR_INTERNET_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT_NEEDED` is to show a Dialog Box to ask the user to choose one (from system store). If you really need the full example, you can considerate the one of blog. Considere it. I'm doing just like that!